# Evaluating integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

I am having trouble figuring out an algebraic trick to make this work

Evaluate the integral

$$\int_1^9\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$

I know I can turn the integrand into $(x-1)     (1/\sqrt{x})$ but I still don't know how to do products of intregrals.

Comment: break the integrand into $\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ or substitute $x=u^2$.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** break the integral into $\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ or try substituting $x=u^2$.

Comment: I got $x^.5 - x^-/5$ and the answer is wrong.

Comment: You still have to integrate $\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: Ah you mean find what function has that as a derivative? I forgot to.

Answer (score 6):

You **cannot** make the integrand $x-1(1/\sqrt{x})$; you **can** make it $(x-1)(1/\sqrt{x})$. Those parentheses are important. However, you don’t want to do any such thing. You want to divide it out. Rewrite the integrand as $$\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac1{\sqrt x}$$ and simplify each term to a power of $x$. Then integrate term by term.